# How to get Gmail edit area with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, gmail

I need to get the `textarea` used by Gmail for composing an email (is it a `textarea` at all?). How can I do this?

Comment: Are you trying to access the data contained in gmail via javascript? For what purpose? Or are you looking to replicate the functionality?

Comment: What exactly do you need to do? If you're in simple text mode it is a textarea, otherwise they use their proprietary editor, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137556/javascript-wysiwyg-editor-used-by-gmail

Comment: @Bulk I am trying to access the data from a javascript bookmarklet in order to do some custom corrections (sort of like spell-checking).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Basic HTML version the textarea is:

```
<textarea name=body title="Message Body" rows=15 cols=50 wrap=virtual class=mi>
```

In the full version it's a Google custom editor, and not a textarea.